# Reading from socket until client sends EOL in C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a basic socket server that looks like this:

```
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
    Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    try
    {
        newsock.Bind(localEndPoint);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Errors handled
    }
    newsock.Listen(10);
    Console.WriteLine("Bound to port 8000");
    Socket client = newsock.Accept();
    while (client.Connected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection recieved.");
        string outputString = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
        client.Receive(buffer);
        string bit = null;
        while (bit != "\r\n" || bit != "\n" || bit != "\r")
        {
            bit = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
            outputString += bit;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(outputString);
    }
```

Right now I want it to accept input until the user (telnet currently) sends an EOL (presses enter) the code above is mostly what I've tried thus far, how should I be doing this?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a TcpListener/TcpClient?  That would make it much easier to use StreamReader.ReadLine()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, TCP works in streams, so in order to detect anything, you are going to have to anticipate the case that a \r\n is not the only thing that is in your buffer.

Replace

```
bit != "\r\n" || bit != "\n" || bit != "\r"
```

with

```
!bit.Contains("\r") && !bit.Contains("\n")
```

Don't forget to repopulate 'bit' with data from the TCPStream... meaning in

```
while (bit != "\r\n" || bit != "\n" || bit != "\r")
{
    bit = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
    outputString += bit;
}
```

you need

```
client.Receive(buffer);
```

so it looks like:

```
while (bit != "\r\n" || bit != "\n" || bit != "\r")
{
    bit = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
    outputString += bit;
    client.Receive(buffer);
}
```

And... an exception handler will let you know when the client disconnects.

Comment: Some of what you mentioned was taken care of and just not posted.  But this worked just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting more than one character when the EOL character is sent try:

```
while (bit != null && !bit.EndsWith("\r") && !bit.EndsWith("\n") )
```